# map common properties in separate method using generics

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, .net-core

I have a class `MechanicalData` and in that i have list of objects and in the below function i am trying to form list of objects with values coming from input.

Mechanicaldata class looks like below

```
public class MechanicalData
{
    public List<LibraryA170> AirflowsA170 { get; set; }
    ......
}
```

and the classes `libraryA170` and `LibraryAcoustic` looks like as follows

```
public class LibraryA170 : AEIMasterBase
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string SpaceFunction { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(32)")]
    public DirectExhaust? DirectExhaust { get; set; }
    .....
    ......
}

public class LibraryAcoustic : AEIMasterBase
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string SpaceFunction { get; set; }
    public double? NoiseCriteria { get; set; }
    .......
}
```

and base class `AEIMasterBase` looks like as below

```
public class AEIMasterBase
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public MasterSection MasterSection { get; set; }
    public List<string> NotesHTML { get; set; }
    public bool? IsApproved { get; set; }
    public Guid? InitialRevisionId { get; set; }
    public Guid? LatestRevisionId { get; set; }
    public int? Revision { get; set; }
 }
```

Below i am trying to map all those fields with LINQ select

```
    private static MechanicalData TransformedMechanicalData(MechanicalData sourceMechanicalData, Dictionary<string, MasterSection> masterSectionMappedLibrary)
    {         
        return new MechanicalData
        {
            AirflowsA170 = sourceMechanicalData.AirflowsA170.Select(airflow170 => new LibraryA170
            {
                Id = airflow170.Id, 
                InitialRevisionId = airflow170.InitialRevisionId,
                LatestRevisionId = airflow170.LatestRevisionId,
                IsApproved = true,
                Revision = airflow170.Revision,
                NotesHTML = airflow170.NotesHTML,
                SpaceFunction = airflow170.SpaceFunction,
                Category = airflow170.Category,
                MasterSection = masterSectionMappedLibrary["Library A170"],
                ........
            }).ToList(),

            Acoustic = sourceMechanicalData.Acoustic.Select(acoustic => new LibraryAcoustic
            {
                Id = acoustic.Id,
                InitialRevisionId = acoustic.InitialRevisionId,
                LatestRevisionId = acoustic.LatestRevisionId,
                IsApproved = true,
                Revision = acoustic.Revision,
                NotesHTML = acoustic.NotesHTML,
                Category = acoustic.Category,
                SpaceFunction = acoustic.SpaceFunction,
                ......
            }).ToList()
        };
    }
```

is there any way i can pass two objects to a method and map common properties inside that method and leave uncommon properties to be mapped inside the select statement while adding to the list.
I am looking for something like as below if possible

```
public static class ItemExtensionMethods
{
    public static readonly Expression<Func<Item, MinimalItem>> MapToMinimalItemExpr = 
        source => new MinimalItem 
        {
            Id = source.Id,  // only common properties like id, revision, IsApproved 
            Property1 = source.Property1
        };
}
```

below are some common properties

```
  Id = airflow170.Id, 
  InitialRevisionId = airflow170.InitialRevisionId,
  LatestRevisionId = airflow170.LatestRevisionId,
  .......
```

Could any one please suggest any idea on this, Many thanks in advance

**update** getting below error

[image]

Comment: Try looking into AutoMapper and see how they handle inheritance mapping: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html

Comment: i cannot use automapper here

Comment: could any one please suggest any idea on this

Comment: @KingOfArrows is there any other way to achieve this

Comment: How about making a public/protected function in each class in the inheritance tree called MapToXXX(XX objectToMap). Then in each function you call base.MapToXXX and pass in the same parameter where after that you assign properties at that classes level. This way for example when you have a new empty LibraryA170 variable called `newLibrary` and an existing filled librarycalled `existingLibrary` you can just go `existingLibrary.MapToLibrary(newLibrary)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given two expression tree's, you want to locate the two `MemberInitExpression` nodes, merge their `MemberBinding`'s and swap any `ParameterExpression`.

```cs
class LocateBindings : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public IEnumerable<MemberBinding> Bindings { get; private set; }
    protected override Expression VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression node)
    {
        Bindings = node.Bindings;
        return base.VisitMemberInit(node);
    }
}

class MergeBindings : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private IEnumerable<MemberBinding> bindings;
    private ParameterExpression parameter;
    public MergeBindings(IEnumerable<MemberBinding> bindings, ParameterExpression parameter)
    {
        this.bindings = bindings;
        this.parameter = parameter;
    }
    protected override Expression VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression node)
        => node.Update(node.NewExpression, 
            node.Bindings.Concat(bindings)
                .Select(VisitMemberBinding));
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        => parameter;
}

public static Expression<Func<P, D>> Merge<BP, P, B, D>(
    Expression<Func<BP, B>> baseExpr,
    Expression<Func<P, D>> derivedExpr
)
    where D:B where P:BP
{
    var locate = new LocateBindings();
    locate.Visit(baseExpr);

    var merge = new MergeBindings(locate.Bindings, derivedExpr.Parameters[0]);
    return merge.VisitAndConvert(derivedExpr, "");
}
```

For example;

```cs
Expression<Func<[insert type], AEIMasterBase>> baseExpression = basearg => new AEIMasterBase
{
    Id = basearg.Id, 
    InitialRevisionId = basearg.InitialRevisionId,
    LatestRevisionId = basearg.LatestRevisionId,
    IsApproved = true,
    Revision = basearg.Revision,
    NotesHTML = basearg.NotesHTML,
    SpaceFunction = basearg.SpaceFunction,
};
Expression<Func<[insert type], LibraryA170>> derivedExpression = airflow170 => new LibraryA170
{
    Category = airflow170.Category,
    MasterSection = masterSectionMappedLibrary["Library A170"],
};
var merged = Merge(baseExpression, derivedExpression);

...
AirflowsA170 = sourceMechanicalData.AirflowsA170.Select(merged).ToList()
...
```

Comment: many thanks for suggestion and i would like assign some custom values as well like this for example in one of the properties `MasterSection = masterSectionMappedLibrary["Library A170"],`

Comment: It shouldn't matter how complicated the input expressions are. We're just moving the member bindings from one expression to another.

Comment: how can i call the above function in `return new MechanicalData{   }`

Comment: `...AirflowsA170.Select( Merge(...) )` Move your current lambda's to local / static variables so you can reuse them. Though you might want to cache the merged expression, unless it captures local variables.

Comment: Sorry getting an error at here `Expression<Func<Item, AEIMasterBase>>` the type or namespace  `Item` could not be found

Comment: That's what you used in your example. The expressions should match whatever expression type your `AirflowsA170.Select(...)` needs.

Comment: yeah, but the problem is i have `MasterSection` property in base class where i am assigning the value like based on derived class name like this `MasterSection = masterSectionMappedLibrary["Library A170"],` how to assign this in the above code

Comment: and here the Item is also a `AEIMasterBase` that is what i am mapping to , should i replace `item` with `AEIMasterBase`

Comment: I was wondering where to define these ones `baseExpression` and `DerivedExpression` and `merge`. I am returning that mechanical data from a static method, do you want me move these into that method

Comment: Right now i am assigning one of the base class property like this `MasterSection = masterSectionMappedLibrary["Library A170"],` how to achieve the same in the above code

Comment: Updated my answer to better reflect the example in your question

Comment: many thanks for the  update sorry i am getting error at here `AirflowsA170 = sourceMechanicalData.AirflowsA170.Select(merged).ToList()` i have updated the question
`

Comment: getting this kind of error `List<AirflowsA170> does not contain definition for select`

Comment: Could you please suggest any idea on how to overcome that issue

Comment: could you please suggest any idea on this the select query is expecting iqueryable

Comment: `IQueryable.Select` takes an `Expression<Func...>`, `IEnumerable.Select` takes a `Func...`, so you'd have to compile it.

Comment: I am updating List<Airflow170> but still getting same error